# Return to application from settings intent

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, return

In my applicattion i need to go to de settings activity of the phone whith the next code:

```
`Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(myIntent);´
```

Then in the settings activity, when the user press BACK key, i want to return to my applicattion ¿it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: This is the standard behavior and on back press in settings you will goto your activity provided you do not finish it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because you have put your code in onCreate() method. Try to movie it to onStart() method. Them when user click back button this method will be called.

For more info about activity life cycle please see [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically go back to the previous activity when the back key is pressed. I use the location settings activity in one of my apps and when the user presses back it returns them to the app. The only time it might not happen is if your app is closed to free memory for another app/service, but this is very unlikely if you are just opening the location settings .

Comment: In my application by pressing the backKey, does not return to my activity, return to the phone's application menu. Should I call otherwise the code that I put it? or Do I have to configure something special in the android manifest?

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the hardware, i do not know of a way to intercept the back key press from a settings activity, i dont think it is possible. Sorry!